# How to use a Python output in app built with C-sharp (API or Ironpython)?

Tags: python, c#, api, xamarin, ironpython

For a project, i've written a program in Python to calculate the angle of arrival of sound. Now, alongside this, we also have made an app using Xamarin in C#.

I want to display the Python output, i.e. the angle, in the app, but what would be the best way to do that? I think an API is a bit overkill but this is certainly not my area of expertise, hence this question.

Writing the program in C# isn't an option, because the libraries I used are of course not available in C#.

Edit: The app receives a WAV file from a Sony Spresense board (arduino like microcontroller) and with that WAV file, the angle of sound is computed using Python. But the problem is that we don't know how to 'send' this file and use it in the Python program and then send it's output back to the app.
We can already send it the file to the App by the way using bluetooth, it's only the python part that we haven't figured out yet

Comment: "best" is a matter of opinion and off-topic for SO.  You haven't really given enough details about your requirements to offer any concrete advice.

Comment: It's for a school project. We have already made the web app and phone app using Xamarin. The Python program is also written and give a float as output. The only thing remaining is displaying this output in the app.
We are automation engineers students, so API's and stuff like that aren't really our expertise.

Comment: The app receives a WAV file from a Sony Spresense board (arduino like microcontroller) and with that WAV file, the angle of sound is computed using Python. But the problem is that we don't know how to 'send' this file and use it in the Python program and then send it's output back to the app.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+python+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.